# Create H.264 packet trace from video

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, ns-3

I'm using **ns-3** for real time video transmission. The peculiarity of my scenario is that, using **JSVM** software, I obtain a text file corresponding to the trace video packets encoded using **H.264/SVC**. After a little bit of post processing, I get an input file suitable for network simulation; then, I try to reconstruct the trace with the packets at the receiver, and after that of course I elaborate some metrics to compare different transmission strategy.
However, last update on JSVM seems to quite [old](https://github.com/floriandejonckheere/jsvm/tree/master/JSVM/H264Extension). In fact, if some (**not fundamental**) packets are missing from the received trace, the bitstream is reconstructed but video decoding procedure won't finish (which to me seems counter-intuitive given H.264 decoding policies).
This means that I can potentially obtain inconsistent metrics.

I tried also **ffmpeg** for the bitstream processing procedure, but in this case it doesn't recognize the enhancement quality layer which I encoded in my video-stream.

Given all the listed problems, I would like to know if there's any software that, given a video with any extension as input, it returns as output a text file corresponding to the packet trace. Moreover, it is important that it can do also the reverse process: from a packet trace text file, it must reconstruct the bit stream.

Comment: I suggest posting your question on the ns-3 mailing list - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ns-3-users

Comment: I was thinking that maybe this was OT for that mailing list.. I'll try anyway. Thanks